# Android Download Zip From Api And Store in SD CARD

Tags: android, file, download, zip

I am working on an API which returns me a zip file containing multiple XML files, which i have to parse individually after extracting the zip file.

Here is the link for that(will download the zip-file) :

> http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=&recr=&rslt=&type=&cond=&intr=&outc=&lead=&spons=&id=&state1=&cntry1=&state2=&cntry2=&state3=&cntry3=&locn=&gndr=Female&age=0&rcv_s=&rcv_e=&lup_s=&lup_e=studyxml=true

## Here is my current code to save the zip-file in sdcard:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String url= "http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=&recr=&rslt=&type=&cond=&intr=&outc=&lead=&spons=&id=&state1=&cntry1=&state2=&cntry2=&state3=&cntry3=&locn=&gndr=Female&age=0&rcv_s=&rcv_e=&lup_s=&lup_e=xml=true";


try {

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(10000); // timeout 10 secs
    conn.connect();
    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();

    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(root, "new.zip"));
    int byteCount = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {

        fOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        byteCount += bytesRead;

    }
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Problem :
New.zip File is getting created in sdcard but it seems nothing is downloading also the file size is 0kb.
Is my code proper or I have to use something else to handel zipfiles.

## Edit Solved :

I am extremely sorry the api link is invalid ... it should be

http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=&recr=&rslt=&type=&cond=&intr=&outc=&lead=&spons=&id=&state1=&cntry1=&state2=&cntry2=&state3=&cntry3=&locn=&gndr=Female&age=0&rcv_s=&rcv_e=&lup_s=&lup_e=&studyxml=true

& is required before studtxml..

Thnx every 1 for quick response ..

Comment: Is your url zip file name contains any space?

Comment: Do you find any exception in logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something **wrong either in your .zip file URL** or in **.zip file size(0 byte size)** because if we download this .zip file (From URL given by you) from web browser then also its downloaded with 0 byte size.

[Downloaded .zip file URL](http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=&recr=&rslt=&type=&cond=&intr=&outc=&lead=&spons=&id=&state1=&cntry1=&state2=&cntry2=&state3=&cntry3=&locn=&gndr=Female&age=0&rcv_s=&rcv_e=&lup_s=&lup_e=studyxml=true).

Answer (score 1):

Your Url in the code `String url=...` is not giving me a zip file.

http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=&recr=&rslt=&type=&cond=&intr=&outc=&lead=&spons=&id=&state1=&cntry1=&state2=&cntry2=&state3=&cntry3=&locn=&gndr=Female&age=0&rcv_s=&rcv_e=&lup_s=&lup_e=xml=true

The link you provided is different

http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=&recr=&rslt=&type=&cond=&intr=&outc=&lead=&spons=&id=&state1=&cntry1=&state2=&cntry2=&state3=&cntry3=&locn=&gndr=Female&age=0&rcv_s=&rcv_e=&lup_s=&lup_e=studyxml=true

Looks like there's an error: `lup_e=xml=true` should be `lup_e=studyxml=true`

Comment: Yes that seems to be the problem i will check on it ASAP , i guess the api link provided to me is wrong.

Thanx For quick response guyzz.. @user370305